# Form validation incorrect

Tags: python, file-upload, wtforms

I have a function which provides validation for files types that are input into my form. Here is the important part...

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('Thanks %s, we will try to get back to your regarding you application as soon as possible.' % form.name.data) 
        print "Form successfully submitted"
        submit_name = form.file_upload.data.filename
        if '.' in submit_name and submit_name.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in FILE_TYPES:
            filename = secure_filename(submit_name)
            form.file_upload.data.save('uploads/' + filename)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            flash('File %s is not an accepted format' % submit_name)
```

When the form is submitted without a file, I still receive the flash message 'file ... is not an accepted format'. However I don't want a flash message if there is no file inserted. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `print submit_name` right before the inner `if` to see what it is

Comment: Well my problem is when no file is submitted the flash is still returning so if i print submit_name nothing will appear as the file field will be empty.

Comment: You'd first need to check if filename is empty.

Comment: Filename is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add:

```
elif submit_name == ""
```

then the flash message

```
flash('File %s is not an accepted format' % submit_name)
```

and also delete the else statement to fix the issue.